# How to setup Microsoft Test Manager projects and CI with an existing solution, without exposing source code to QA?

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, microsoft-test-manager

In an existing TFS project, we have created a code repository using Git.

I would like to create a new repository within that project that QA can access, but not be able to access any other repositories within the project.

I would like to ensure that MTM projects are synced with releases for CI.

How can this be accomplished without creating a separate QA project - which I have tried?  I don't see how we would be able to sync test cases from one project with another in CI.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the question. TFS has repository-level security already. If the QA team shouldn't have access to a repository, don't give them access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use branch to achieve what you want like below

```
      -mastet
      -Devloper (Source code)
      -QA team (for tester)
```

Some branchs for Devloper team and one branch for testers. To forbid QA team access to any other branch within the project. You must set permissions for your QA team and the branch. Such as, set the QA team read access of other brach to dendy. The easiest way to set permission you can through web portal administrator page. Moreover, which project of 'MTM projects' and 'from one project' did you mean? Is it a team project or a VS project?